Trying to record audio using Pulse audio and FFMPEG but no audio in generated file
I am trying to record output generated by google chrome which i open in headless mode in pupeteer on a docker container without a sound card. I have used pulseaudio to create a null sink and using ffmpeg to record the sound being sent to null sink but everytime the generated file has no audio. Tried with even Xvfb setup but same result.
Below is the pulse audio log file along with ffmpeg command used to record. I have also listed output of pactl list sinks command. Can anyone let me know what am i doing wrong?
Pactl List Sinks:
pactl list sinks
Sink #0
        State: RUNNING
        Name: auto_null
        Description: Dummy Output
        Driver: module-null-sink.c
        Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        Channel Map: front-left,front-right
        Owner Module: 7
        Mute: no
        Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        Monitor Source: auto_null.monitor
        Latency: 1077 usec, configured 11610 usec
        Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
        Properties:
                device.description = "Dummy Output"
                device.class = "abstract"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card"
        Formats:
                pcm

FFmpeg command:
ffmpeg -f pulse -i auto_null.monitor -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -vsync 0 -t 120 -fflags +genpts -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -af aresample=async=1 output.wav```

FFmpeg error:
tarting FFmpeg recording: ffmpeg -f pulse -i auto_null.monitor -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -vsync 0 -t 120 -fflags +genpts -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -af aresample=async=1 output.wav
FFmpeg Output: 
FFmpeg Errors: ffmpeg version 4.3.7-0+deb11u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, pulse, from 'auto_null.monitor':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1727772983.182123, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, wav, to 'output.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 pcm_s16le
size=   22500kB time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=1536.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
video:0kB audio:22500kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000339%

Ffmpeg Code:
async function startRecording(outputFile) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fullCommand = `${ffmpegCommand} ${outputFile}`;
    console.log('Starting FFmpeg recording:', fullCommand);

    const recordingProcess = exec(fullCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error during recording with FFmpeg:', error);
        reject(error);
      } else {
        console.log('FFmpeg Output:', stdout);
        console.error('FFmpeg Errors:', stderr);
        resolve(outputFile);
      }
    });
    


PulseAudio Log file:
[pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode, but --disallow-exit not set.
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode, but --disallow-module-loading not set.
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode, forcibly disabling SHM mode.
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode, forcibly disabling exit idle time.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to acquire high-priority scheduling: Input/output error
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found user 'pulse' (UID 107) and group 'pulse' (GID 113).
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: Home directory of user 'pulse' is not '/var/run/pulse', ignoring.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Successfully changed user to "pulse".
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 14.2
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/pulseaudio-eJtUKc/pulseaudio-14.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-color=auto
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 6.10.4-linuxkit #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Aug 12 08:48:58 UTC 2024
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 12 CPUs.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: yes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running from build tree: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 7cf3639ce59149fdb7f448efbcf152c9.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /var/run/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /var/lib/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-14.2/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: yes
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: OK, so you are running PA in system mode. Please make sure that you actually do want to do that.
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: Please read http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/WhatIsWrongWithSystemWide/ for an explanation why system mode is usually a bad idea.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: System appears to not support high resolution timers
D: [pulseaudio] memblock.c: Using private memory pool with 1024 slots of size 64.0 KiB each, total size is 64.0 MiB, maximum usable slot size is 65472
I: [pulseaudio] cpu-x86.c: CPU flags: CMOV MMX SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] sconv_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized conversions.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_orc.c: Initialising ORC optimized volume functions.
D: [pulseaudio] database-tdb.c: Opened TDB database '/var/lib/pulse/7cf3639ce59149fdb7f448efbcf152c9-device-volumes.tdb'
I: [pulseaudio] database.c: Successfully opened 'device-volumes' database file '/var/lib/pulse/7cf3639ce59149fdb7f448efbcf152c9-device-volumes.tdb'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-device-restore" (index: #0; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] database-tdb.c: Opened TDB database '/var/lib/pulse/7cf3639ce59149fdb7f448efbcf152c9-stream-volumes.tdb'
I: [pulseaudio] database.c: Successfully opened 'stream-volumes' database file '/var/lib/pulse/7cf3639ce59149fdb7f448efbcf152c9-stream-volumes.tdb'.
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-dbus.c: Interface org.PulseAudio.Ext.StreamRestore1 added for object /org/pulseaudio/stream_restore1
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-dbus.c: Interface org.PulseAudio.Ext.StreamRestore1.RestoreEntry added for object /org/pulseaudio/stream_restore1/entry0
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-dbus.c: Interface org.PulseAudio.Ext.StreamRestore1.RestoreEntry added for object /org/pulseaudio/stream_restore1/entry1
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-stream-restore" (index: #1; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] database-tdb.c: Opened TDB database '/var/lib/pulse/7cf3639ce59149fdb7f448efbcf152c9-card-database.tdb'
I: [pulseaudio] database.c: Successfully opened 'card-database' database file '/var/lib/pulse/7cf3639ce59149fdb7f448efbcf152c9-card-database.tdb'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-card-restore" (index: #2; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib/pulse-14.2/modules/module-udev-detect.so': success
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /dev/snd/ is apparently not existing yet, retrying to create inotify watch later.
I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Found 0 cards.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-udev-detect" (index: #3; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib/pulse-14.2/modules/module-esound-protocol-unix.so': failure
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-native-protocol-unix" (index: #4; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-default-device-restore.c: No previous default sink setting, ignoring.
I: [pulseaudio] module-default-device-restore.c: No previous default source setting, ignoring.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-default-device-restore" (index: #5; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module-always-sink.c: Autoloading null-sink as no other sinks detected.
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c: Created sink 0 "auto_null" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.description = "Dummy Output"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.class = "abstract"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-card"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c: Created source 0 "auto_null.monitor" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.description = "Monitor of Dummy Output"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.class = "monitor"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Thread starting up
I: [null-sink] util.c: Failed to acquire real-time scheduling: Input/output error
D: [pulseaudio] sink.c: auto_null: state: INIT -> IDLE
D: [pulseaudio] source.c: auto_null.monitor: state: INIT -> IDLE
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: default_source: (unset) -> auto_null.monitor
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: default_sink: (unset) -> auto_null
D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-null-sink" (index: #7; argument: "sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Dummy Output"'").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-always-sink" (index: #6; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-position-event-sounds" (index: #8; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] dbus-util.c: Successfully connected to D-Bus system bus e92021c10da7a474a61627a366fb90fa as :1.270
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Got org.pulseaudio.Server!
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup complete.
I: [pulseaudio] client.c: Created 0 "Native client (UNIX socket client)"
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Protocol version: remote 34, local 34
I: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Got credentials: uid=0 gid=0 success=1
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: SHM possible: no
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Negotiated SHM: no
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Disabling srbchannel, reason: No SHM support
I: [pulseaudio] client.c: Freed 0 "pactl"
I: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Connection died.
I: [pulseaudio] client.c: Created 1 "Native client (UNIX socket client)"
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Protocol version: remote 34, local 34
I: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Got credentials: uid=0 gid=0 success=1
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: SHM possible: no
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Negotiated SHM: no
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Disabling srbchannel, reason: No SHM support
I: [pulseaudio] client.c: Created 2 "Native client (UNIX socket client)"
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Protocol version: remote 34, local 34
I: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Got credentials: uid=0 gid=0 success=1
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: SHM possible: no
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Negotiated SHM: no
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Disabling srbchannel, reason: No SHM support
D: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Negotiated format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"float32le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Trying to change sample spec
I: [pulseaudio] resampler.c: Forcing resampler 'copy', because of fixed, identical sample rates.
D: [pulseaudio] resampler.c: Resampler:
D: [pulseaudio] resampler.c:   rate 44100 -> 44100 (method copy)
D: [pulseaudio] resampler.c:   format float32le -> s16le (intermediate s16le)
D: [pulseaudio] resampler.c:   channels 2 -> 2 (resampling 2)
D: [pulseaudio] memblockq.c: memblockq requested: maxlength=33554432, tlength=0, base=4, prebuf=0, minreq=1 maxrewind=0
D: [pulseaudio] memblockq.c: memblockq sanitized: maxlength=33554432, tlength=33554432, base=4, prebuf=0, minreq=4 maxrewind=0
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Created input 0 "Playback" on auto_null with sample spec float32le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.icon_name = "google-chrome"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     media.name = "Playback"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.name = "Google Chrome"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     native-protocol.version = "34"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.process.id = "9916"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.process.user = "root"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.process.host = "9b0371b37d54"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.process.binary = "chrome"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.language = "C.UTF-8"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     window.x11.display = ":1"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.process.machine_id = "7cf3639ce59149fdb7f448efbcf152c9"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:Google Chrome"
I: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Requested tlength=34.83 ms, minreq=5.80 ms
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Adjust latency mode enabled, configuring sink latency to half of overall latency.
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Requested latency=11.61 ms, Received latency=11.61 ms
D: [pulseaudio] memblockq.c: memblockq requested: maxlength=4194304, tlength=8192, base=8, prebuf=6152, minreq=2048 maxrewind=0
D: [pulseaudio] memblockq.c: memblockq sanitized: maxlength=4194304, tlength=8192, base=8, prebuf=6152, minreq=2048 maxrewind=0
I: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Final latency 34.83 ms = 11.61 ms + 2*5.80 ms + 11.61 ms
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Requesting rewind due to uncorking
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] source.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Rewound 2048 bytes.
D: [pulseaudio] sink.c: auto_null: state: IDLE -> RUNNING
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 2048 bytes on render memblockq.
D: [null-sink] source.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Rewound 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Requesting rewind due to corking
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 2048 bytes on render memblockq.
D: [null-sink] source.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Rewound 2048 bytes.
D: [pulseaudio] sink.c: auto_null: state: RUNNING -> IDLE
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Requesting rewind due to uncorking
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] source.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Rewound 2048 bytes.
D: [pulseaudio] sink.c: auto_null: state: IDLE -> RUNNING
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Requesting rewind due to corking
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 320 bytes on render memblockq.
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 640 bytes on implementor.
D: [null-sink] source.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Rewound 320 bytes.
D: [pulseaudio] sink.c: auto_null: state: RUNNING -> IDLE
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Requesting rewind due to uncorking
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] source.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Rewound 592 bytes.
D: [pulseaudio] sink.c: auto_null: state: IDLE -> RUNNING
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Requesting rewind due to corking
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 1460 bytes on render memblockq.
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 2920 bytes on implementor.
D: [null-sink] source.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Rewound 1460 bytes.
D: [pulseaudio] sink.c: auto_null: state: RUNNING -> IDLE
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Requesting rewind due to uncorking
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] source.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Rewound 1464 bytes.
D: [pulseaudio] sink.c: auto_null: state: IDLE -> RUNNING
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Implicit underrun of 'Playback'
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Implicit underrun of 'Playback'
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Implicit underrun of 'Playback'
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 792 bytes on render memblockq.
D: [null-sink] source.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Rewound 792 bytes.
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Implicit underrun of 'Playback'
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 180 bytes on render memblockq.
D: [null-sink] source.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Rewound 180 bytes.
I: [pulseaudio] client.c: Created 3 "Native client (UNIX socket client)"
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Protocol version: remote 34, local 34
I: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Got credentials: uid=0 gid=0 success=1
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: SHM possible: no
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Negotiated SHM: no
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Disabling srbchannel, reason: No SHM support
D: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Negotiated format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"float32le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Trying to change sample spec
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c: Cannot update sample spec, SINK_IS_RUNNING, will keep using s16le and 44100 Hz
I: [pulseaudio] resampler.c: Forcing resampler 'copy', because of fixed, identical sample rates.
D: [pulseaudio] resampler.c: Resampler:
D: [pulseaudio] resampler.c:   rate 44100 -> 44100 (method copy)
D: [pulseaudio] resampler.c:   format float32le -> s16le (intermediate s16le)
D: [pulseaudio] resampler.c:   channels 2 -> 2 (resampling 2)
D: [pulseaudio] memblockq.c: memblockq requested: maxlength=33554432, tlength=0, base=4, prebuf=0, minreq=1 maxrewind=0
D: [pulseaudio] memblockq.c: memblockq sanitized: maxlength=33554432, tlength=33554432, base=4, prebuf=0, minreq=4 maxrewind=0
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Created input 1 "Playback" on auto_null with sample spec float32le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.icon_name = "google-chrome"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     media.name = "Playback"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.name = "Google Chrome"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     native-protocol.version = "34"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.process.id = "9916"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.process.user = "root"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.process.host = "9b0371b37d54"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.process.binary = "chrome"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.language = "C.UTF-8"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     window.x11.display = ":1"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     application.process.machine_id = "7cf3639ce59149fdb7f448efbcf152c9"
I: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c:     module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:Google Chrome"
I: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Requested tlength=69.66 ms, minreq=11.61 ms
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Adjust latency mode enabled, configuring sink latency to half of overall latency.
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Requested latency=23.22 ms, Received latency=23.22 ms
D: [pulseaudio] memblockq.c: memblockq requested: maxlength=4194304, tlength=16384, base=8, prebuf=12296, minreq=4096 maxrewind=0
D: [pulseaudio] memblockq.c: memblockq sanitized: maxlength=4194304, tlength=16384, base=8, prebuf=12296, minreq=4096 maxrewind=0
I: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Final latency 69.66 ms = 23.22 ms + 2*11.61 ms + 23.22 ms
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [null-sink] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Requesting rewind due to uncorking
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 180 bytes on render memblockq.
D: [null-sink] source.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Rewound 180 bytes.
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Requesting rewind due to corking
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.
D: [null-sink] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 1192 bytes on render memblockq.
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 1192 bytes on render memblockq.
D: [null-sink] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 2384 bytes on implementor.
D: [null-sink] source.c: Processing rewind...
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Rewound 1192 bytes.
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Requested to rewind 2048 bytes.


You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details, but your paste shows a Debian kernel is being used and not a Ubuntu kernel.

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

wait i have tried this with ubuntu product also, issue remains same. Would it be helpful if i could grab those logs?
